# How to join collection in firestore

Tags: firebase, join, collections, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have to fetch job list with user detail who posted the job.
How can I achieve this task in firestore. As there is no option to joining collections.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to join collection in firestore. So, I used the associated field to get the data from other collection.

Answer (score 1):

you can write cloud functions to join collections on the server side, or you can use rxjs operators to do it on the client side, sorry but cloud firestore still on a beta version so there is some query limations